# Finding the minimal polynomial of $e^{2πi/5}$ over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: minimal-polynomials

How would one find the minimal polynomial of $e^{2πi/5}$ over $\mathbb Q$?

I have tried this:

$$\text {Let } a = e^{2πi/5}$$
$$\implies a = ({e^{2πi}})^{1/5}\implies a = 1^{1/5}\implies a - 1= 0$$

Since the polynomial $a - 1$ is monic and of least degree this therefore must be the minimal polynomial of $e^{2πi/5}$ over $\mathbb Q$?

I can't see why it's wrong, although it's different form related questions on this forum. Can someone show me what's wrong?

Comment: The identity $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c$ fails much more often for complex numbers than it does for real numbers. However, it holds true when $c$ is an integer.

Comment: $$\implies a = ({e^{2πi}})^{1/5}\implies a = 1^{1/5}\implies a - 1= 0$$

Since $a-1=0$ implies $a=1$, it should be obvious you made a mistake somewhere along the way...

Comment: It's wrong because $e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5} } \ne 1$

Comment: $a^5=1$, correct.  But it does not follow that $a=1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

It is not, because $\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2\pi i}5}\ne 1$. Hence the minimal polynomial is a divisor of
$$\frac{X^5-1}{X-1}=X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1.$$
Can you prove this polynomial is irreducible?